# Declare statement in SQL got wrong

Tags: sql, declare

I am doing an exercise from a tutorial, the question are :

Create a table variable and populate it with a list of distinct colors from the SalesLT.Product table. Then use the table variable to filter a query that returns the product ID, name, and color from the SalesLT.Product table so that only products with a color listed in the table variable are returned. You'll need to use NVARCHAR(15) in your solution and make sure to use the aliases provided.

i wrote the following code, but got the wrong message that my DECLARE function are wrong, can you help me to check why, the code works and returns a table with the info required

```
DECLARE @Colors AS TABLE (Color NVARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO @Colors
SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM SalesLT.Product;

SELECT ProductID, Name, Color
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE Color IN (SELECT Color FROM  @Colors);
```

Comment: your declare function looks good to me . Can you put exact error message here ?

Comment: HI THANKS,THE ERROR message i got is :  Is your DECLARE statement correct?  this is a grade question, i will lost credits if i check the final answer..

Comment: It is a standard example so I dont see any issues here may be if you can put entire question here it will put things in perspective .

Comment: Hi , i changed the "Color" in the declare clause and select clause at the end respectively to "Value", now its the right answer, i dont know why, but basically its the same , or isn´t it ?

Comment: Naming a column in a table (`color` vs `value`) is not significant. It is helpful to name columns intuitively, so it is easy to write code. But you can easily call it `value` or `color` or `field1` or anything. It's like typing a column header in Excel, something meaningful helps people understand the data.

Comment: As an improvement you can alias your tables so you do not get any ambiguity issues when the same named columns exists in more than one table, for example:
`SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name, P.Color
FROM SalesLT.Product P
WHERE P.Color IN (SELECT C.Color FROM  @Colors C);`
Also your `IN` statement can be changed to an `EXISTS` to improve performance and stop a table scan.

Comment: Just for reference though, be aware of how pointless this exercise actually is and how you *shouldn't*, in general, break queries down into multiple steps like this. I.e. in general, you shouldn't populate a table variable with a simple query just to then use it inside another query - you should directly embed the first query into the second and let the *system* decide if it should materialize all of those intermediate results.

Comment: @DavidB - if we're truly setting out to optimize the whole lot we'll just `SELECT ProductID, Name, Color
FROM SalesLT.Product` and miss out the table variable and filter entirely. We're filtering down to the distinct set of colors which *were sourced from the entire contents of the same table*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point, I was more trying to explain the concept.

Comment: thanks for all your guys explaination

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Colores TABLE
(
Color NVARCHAR(15)
)
INSERT INTO @Colores(Color)
SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE Color IS NOT NULL

SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color FROM SalesLT.Product as p
JOIN @Colores as c
ON c.Color = p.Color
ORDER BY Color
```

This is the code I came up with and the results are the exact table that they are asking for. Also, since they are asking for the Id, name and color for only those that show up in the table, I believe that you should not take into consideration those with NULL values, since otherwise you are just creating a table variable out from another table, only to recall that same table, which kinda makes no sense to me. I have to admit that the statement of the  exercise could be a bit more clear.